# Scrape all text from a partially visible scroll box using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape data from the public site http://www.seaaroundus.org using selenium-webdriver in Python. I am trying to scrape the values of the options of a list on [this](http://www.seaaroundus.org/data/#/eez/8/exploited-organisms) webpage using the following code. The list is inside a scroll box and partially visible. When I extract the text from the xpath, it only returns the first 11 items on the list. Is there a way to extract the text of all the items in the list? I tried to loop over the xpaths of the different items but they seem to be repeating after every eleventh item so they loop breaks down. I have to do this for about 300 similar webpages. Would appreciate any leads! [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDtA.png)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

#1 open website
driver.get("http://www.seaaroundus.org/data/#/eez/8/exploited-organisms")
time.sleep(5)

#xpath of where all the taxa names are listed
x_path = """//*[@id="exploited-organisms"]/sau-taxon-grid/div[2]/div[1]"""

#printing the xpath.text only prints the first 11 items
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path).text)
```

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and scrap the data directly through the underlying service. Use devtools to monitor the requests and the console to test a script.  For instance `fetch("http://api.seaaroundus.org/api/v1/eez/exploited-organisms/?region_id=8").then(v => v.json()).then(v => console.log(v.data));`.

Comment: Just a tip for you x_xpath declaration, use double quotes outside and single-quote inside xpath. x_path = "//*[@id='exploited-organisms']/sau-taxon-grid/div[2]/div[1]"

Comment: @Wonka, can you explain why this tip might be useful for OP?

Comment: And now a top for your problem, first get the number of total elements ex: Taxa (63) -> total = 63.
Meanwhile elements you are obtained is not total, scroll.
This works to scroll on main  page, im sure you will find the solution to scroll the part that you want
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: @Andersson just for 4 less characters to write ;) and to be able to copy/paste to test XPath in Developers tools Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Florent B. correctly suggested you can simply use direct HTTP request to API to get required data:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://api.seaaroundus.org/api/v1/eez/exploited-organisms/?region_id=8'

response = requests.get(url)

for fish in response.json()['data']:
    print("{} ({})".format(fish["common_name"], fish["scientific_name"]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that does it perfectly!

Comment: @MihirSharma , welcome. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem